# Navigating website using selenium

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape information from a website but am having trouble navigating it using Selenium. The site uses ng-click to update a table so I must activate different tabs on the page to get the information I want. This is the html that generates the tabs:

```
<ul class="tabs swiper-wrapper" ng-class="{'swiper-wrapper' : swiperActive }">
    <li ng-repeat="category in Report.Winners track by $index" ng-click="updateCategory(category.key)" ng-class="{'active' : category.key == activeCategory, 'swiper-slide' : swiperActive }" class="ng-scope active">
        <p class="category text-small ng-binding">Category 1</p>
        <p class="winner">
        </p>
    </li><li ng-repeat="category in Report.Winners track by $index" ng-click="updateCategory(category.key)" ng-class="{'active' : category.key == activeCategory, 'swiper-slide' : swiperActive }" class="ng-scope">
        <p class="category text-small ng-binding">Category 2</p>
        <p class="winner">
        </p>
    </li><li ng-repeat="category in Report.Winners track by $index" ng-click="updateCategory(category.key)" ng-class="{'active' : category.key == activeCategory, 'swiper-slide' : swiperActive }" class="ng-scope">
        <p class="category text-small ng-binding">Category 3</p>
        <p class="winner">
        </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have figured out how to scrape the information from "Category 1" since it loads by default. How do I navigate to "Category 2" and "Category 3" so I can scrape those as well? Thanks!

**Update:**
I ended up using this to find the links for each category:

```
available_categories_links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("ul > [ng-click*=updateCategory]")
```

And then I loop through them like this:

```
for x in range(len(available_categories_links)):
    available_categories_links[x].click()
```

Doing it this way doesn't let me access different tabs by name like I had originally hoped to do, and it's probably not the most efficient or very robust, but it gets the job done in my particular case.

Comment: have you tried finding elements by link text? for example `driver.find_element_by_link_text("Category 2")`

Comment: yes, I have tried that. I get a "NoSuchElementException" when I do. I think this is because the text I want to search for is a child of the element I want to click?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your tabs load on runtime.
So, to activate the tab, you need to use FindElement(By) to locate the tab and click it before you could access the information from that tab.

According to your code, no Id found to use FindElement(By.Id). So I suggest you use either FindElement(By.CSSSelector) or FindElement(By.Xpath) which you could copy the Locator string from browser's development tool, i.e. in Google Chrome right click==> inspect==>Copy==>Copy Selector or Copy Xpath.

After you got the Tab Element, i.e.

```
IWebElement tab = driver.FindElement(By.CSSSelector);

tab.Click();//Tab activated
//...Do your thing afterwards.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think OP is using Selenium with python bindings.